# How to convert locale date to the timestamp

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone

How can I convert "9月 17, 2019" to the timestamp long value using moment?

I have tried using below code to convert but no luck.

```
moment('9月 17, 2019').tz('zh-cn')
      .endOf('day')
      .format('x')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `moment-timezone` understands timezone identifier `zh-cn`.

Howerer, if you want to convert this string using `moment` you can do it like this:

```js
let x = moment('9月 17, 2019', 'MM月 DD, YYYY')
  .endOf('day')
  .format('x');

console.log(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```